# PEAR errors in a separate popup window

Tags: php, pear

I am working with some legacy code & have upgraded to an Apache 2.4 server with php 5.5.  When some of the legacy code runs, a separate window pops up with a list of PEAR errors:

```
[2014-11-09 18:04:44](0x800) in C:\php\pear\DB\DataObject.php on line 4672
Non-static method PEAR::getStaticProperty() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
[2014-11-09 18:04:44](0x800) in C:\php\pear\DB\DataObject.php on line 2455
Non-static method DB::connect() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
[2014-11-09 18:04:44](0x800) in C:\php\pear\DB\mysql.php on line 48
Declaration of DB_mysql::quote() should be compatible with DB_common::quote($string = NULL)
```

...

How do you turn this off?

My php.ini settings are:

```
error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

but I imaging PEAR has it's own error levels. I just can't seem to find them.  Any ideas on where to look?

Comment: The popup window is titled "ErrorHandler Console:"

Answer (score 0):

There is a function errorConf() that apparently is getting called.  This is a

```
function errorConf() {
    require_once 'common/ErrorHandler.inc'; 
    return new ErrorHandler();
}
```

And is bringing up this popup:
    window.open("", "ErrorHandlerConsole","...");

I've simply made the function blank function errorConf() {} but may look in to more responsible handling if i have time.

Thanks for anyone who took time to read all this.